# Change website language

Tags: c#

```
string text = "我喜欢跑步。";
TranslateClient client = new TranslateClient(/* Enter the URL of your site here */);
string translated = client.Translate(text, Language.ChineseSimplified, Language.English);
Console.WriteLine(translated);  // I like running.
```

It is working fine. But I want to pass whole site as an input and convert into selected language. How can I do this?

Ex : http://translate.google.com/#

Answer (score 0):

You may need to fetch the page contents yourself, for instance using [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx), strip it by HTML elements (with a simple regular expression),  then feed it the text to code that does the translation.

Comment: Actually when I try to pass my web page source like this

WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
            wclient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2)");
            Stream data = wclient.OpenRead("http://www.google.com");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
string text = s;
TranslateClient client = new TranslateClient(/*Enter the URL of your site here */);string translated = client.Translate(text, Language.ChineseSimplified, Language.English);Console.WriteLine(translated); Plz